# Why is it that every DIY plumbing job requires two extra trips to the hardware store?

Tags: plumbing

You plan.  You measure.  You re-measure.  You plan some more.

You write it all down.

You go to the hardware store and buy EVERYTHING you could possibly need, plus extra.

You come home, you go to work.

And inevitably something happens that you completely didn't expect and you have to go back to the hardware store.  Not only that, when you go, you get something wrong, so you end up going back AGAIN.

Every time!  Every single time?

Why is this?

Comment: I don't get this, you already have a [Peer Pressure](http://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=3525) badge.

Comment: I'm bloody well ticked off and letting off steam.  Read the tags.

Comment: You know what will relax you?  A nice shopping trip to Home Depot!

Comment: I hate you.  Lots.

Comment: Sorry for being the party pooper.

Comment: Not constructive my behind.  It made ME feel better ;)

Comment: It's the law. I've even seen professionals with vans full of parts plagued by it. Don't tick off the plumbing Gods or you spend eternal time on the road. And if you're in southern Oregon, you can stop in at Grover's. Not as big as the big box, but a plumbing Temple of one of the lesser gods.

Answer (score 1):

It's a law of nature. Or physics. Well, Murphy's law, at least.

FWIW, I envision in 10 years time that we'll finally have affordable 3-D printers that can print in metal. No more trips just for that one special bold/screw/washer!

Comment: Brilliant - instead we'll have to wait 2 hours for the print and 4 hours for the heat cure... :/